# neilime / zf2-assets-bundle and Base64 Asset

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, assets

Does anyone know how to make this work ?

in css

```
background:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAAMCAYAAABWdVznAAAAYUlEQVR42mP4////P1IwA5RBNIBr+Pj5+/9Tlx78v373OYoCkBgIY2gACWr7tP63CO8BanoBlmyfuQssBsIYGtAVLNpwEsMADA0gAFMIw+hOpEwDSU4i2dMkByvJEUcsAABHaALCQIZDrAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
```

Error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message `'"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAAMCAYAAABWdVznAAAAYUlEQVR42mP4////P1IwA5RBNIBr+Pj5+/9Tlx78v373OYoCkBgIY2gACWr7tP63CO8BanoBlmyfuQssBsIYGtAVLNpwEsMADA0gAFMIw+hOpEwDSU4i2dMkByvJEUcsAABHaALCQIZDrAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" has not been cached as file "public/cache/data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAAMCAYAAABWdVznAAAAYUlEQVR42mP4////P1IwA5RBNIBr+Pj5+/9Tlx78v373OYoCkBgIY2gACWr7tP63CO8BanoBlmyfuQssBsIYGtAVLNpwEsMADA0gAFMIw+hOpEwDSU4i2dMkByvJEUcsAABHaALCQIZDrAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="' in vendor/neilime/zf2-assets-bundle/src/AssetsBundle/Service/Service.php on line 855`
```

Is there a built-in solution for base 64 encoded media like this png ?

Comment: https://github.com/neilime/zf2-assets-bundle/issues/25
Bug was fixed and work as expected.